# Proof Intermediate Value Theorem: Correct?

Tags: continuity

Theorem:

Let $f: [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and let $f(a)<d<f(b)$, then $ \exists c \in [a,b] $ such that $ f(c)=d$.

Proof:

Consider the set $H=\{x∈[a,b]:f(x)<d\}≠∅$, since $H$ is bounded, it has supremum $c\in [a,b]$. There are three cases:

1. $f(c)=d$
2. $f(c)<d$
3. $f(c)>d$

For case 1 we are done, and the theorem holds.

For the second case: Suppose $f(c)<d$. In partricular $c\in H$ and, moreover $a<c<b$, because by asssumption $f(a)<d$ and $f(b)>d$. By continuity of $f$ at $c$, there's $\delta >0$ such that $a<c-\delta <c+\delta <b$ and $|x-c|<\delta \implies f(x)<d$ (by considering the continuous function $d-f(x)$ wchich is positive at c). Bbut then $c+ \frac{\delta}{2} \in H$, becasue $f(c+ \frac{\delta}{2})<d$. A contradiction to the fact that $c=supH$.

For the third case: Suppose $f(c)>d$. By continuity of $f$ at $c$, there's $\delta >0$ such that $a<c-\delta <c+\delta <b$ and $|x-c|<\delta \implies f(x)>d$. But by definition of supremum, there is $x\in H$ such that $c-x<\delta$; for this $x$ we have both $f(x)<d$ and $f(x)>d$, a contradiction. Therefore we conclude that $f(c)=d$.

Is this proof valid?

Comment: Why do you assume the first and the third case? You have defined $H$ in a way such that $\forall x \in H$ the image of $x$ is $<d$

Comment: What should I change?

Comment: Aren't you considering unnecesary cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case 2, technically you didn't rule out the case $c=a$, which would have prevented you from choosing such a $\delta$. This problem is easily fixed though.

Similarly in case 3, what if $c=d$.

Otherwise everything looks good!

Comment: But since we have that $f(a)<f(c)<f(b)$ doesn't this imply that $c \neq a $ and $c\neq b$ sice its image is strictly smaller than the image of d and strictly bigger than the image of a?